static assertion fires from return type when leading constraint is not satisfied
GCC accepts this code, Clang and MSVC reject it due to failed static assertion in assert.
What does the standard say?
https://godbolt.org/z/PKMKzYGsc
template<typename T>
constexpr int assert() {
    static_assert(sizeof(T) == 1);
    return 1;
}

template<auto I>
using Int = int;

template<typename T> requires (sizeof(T) == 1)
constexpr auto foo(T) -> Int<assert<T>()> {
    return 1;
}

template<typename T> requires (sizeof(T) > 1)
constexpr auto foo(T a) -> Int<1> {
    return 2;
}

static_assert(foo('1') == 1);
static_assert(foo(2) == 2);

Clang output:
<source>:3:19: error: static assertion failed due to requirement 'sizeof(int) == 1'
    3 |     static_assert(sizeof(T) == 1);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:11:30: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'assert<int>' requested here
   11 | constexpr auto foo(T) -> Int<assert<T>()> {
      |                              ^
<source>:21:15: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'foo' [with T = int]
   21 | static_assert(foo(2) == 2);
      |               ^
<source>:3:29: note: expression evaluates to '4 == 1'
    3 |     static_assert(sizeof(T) == 1);


Always post complete error along with your question.

Also note that the problem is only with the second statement static_assert(foo(2) == 2);. The first statement static_assert(foo('1') == 1); compiles by all three compilers.

Clang and msvc seems to be wrong.

This is CWG 2369, which it appears that clang and MSVC do not yet implement.

During template argument deduction, the satisfaction check of the function template's associated constraints takes place before the substitution of template arguments into the function type. This is described in [temp.deduct.general]/5:

If the function template has associated constraints, those constraints are checked for satisfaction. If the constraints are not satisfied, type deduction fails. [...] If type deduction has not yet failed, then all uses of template parameters in the function type are replaced with the corresponding deduced or default argument values.

This means that type deduction should fail before encountering the problematic assert in this example, making it well-formed.
This outcome is the result of CWG2369, prior to which the two steps above happened in the opposite order. Evidently, Clang and MSVC don't implement this change yet, leading to the observed implementation divergence.

The program is well-formed and gcc is correct in accepting the code as explained below.
From over.over:

All functions with associated constraints that are not satisfied ([temp.constr.decl]) are eliminated from the set of selected functions.
If more than one function in the set remains, all function template specializations in the set are eliminated if the set also contains a function that is not a function template specialization.
Any given non-template function F0 is eliminated if the set contains a second non-template function that is more constrained than F0 according to the partial ordering rules of [temp.constr.order].
Any given function template specialization F1 is eliminated if the set contains a second function template specialization whose function template is more specialized than the function template of F1 according to the partial ordering rules of [temp.func.order].
After such eliminations, if any, there shall remain exactly one selected function.

(emphasis mine)
This means that for the call foo(2), the version #1 with sizeof(T)==1 will be eliminated from the set of selected functions. And the other one(version #2) that satisfies the constraint will be the only viable candidate and used.

The substitution happens before this elimination as per https://eel.is/c++draft/over.over#3, and the error happens during that substitution. Which means the program is ill-formed, I believe?

@HolyBlackCat The "if any" in over.over#3 seems to indicate that "if the specialization is generated" but here it can't be so this won't be added in the set. And the version 2 can/will be added.

Nope, this interpretation would mean there's no such thing as non-SFIANE-friendliness, but it definitely exists. (It would mean that OP's code should compile without any requires on the functions, but that's surely not the case.)

@HolyBlackCat So the reason for "if any" ?

@HolyBlackCat Without the requires this would be [CWG2369]. So the question is does the substitution happens before the elimination. Or the require  is supposed to take over the substitution failure.

@HolyBlackCat Also why will the substitution failure make this ill-formed? I mean there is a perfectly usable other option that can be used.

Because a static_assert failure is not in the immediate context, so it can't be caught by SFINAE and is always a hard error (aka "not SFINAE-friendly"). So without requires this is always ill-formed regardless of CWG2369. With requires this is ill-formed if specialization happens before elimination.

What I'm missing is how does CWG2369 change the substition vs elimination order exactly? I trusted Barry on this, but I don't see the actual wording change for this, not in https://eel.is/c++draft/over.over

@HolyBlackCat "static_assert failure is not in the immediate context..." So shouldn't this demo should also fail as static_assert cannot use sfinae. I think both [over.over#5] and [cwg2369] are supposed to make this well-formed.

There's no SFINAE in this snippet.

@HolyBlackCat Here is the example with SFINAE and that uses SFINAE without any hard error.

Yeah, but here SFINAE doesn't catch a static_assert failure (my point is that it can't), it's used in static_assert condition (which is allowed, yes).

@user12002570 Here's the example of "static_assert failure is not in the immediate context..."

@VainMan Yes, I know that. But those demos are different. There the static_assert is included in the substitution context unlike the example here(or in my example). In both cases, failure in static_assert will result in hard error  but only when the expression/condition etc withing is invalid and there is no valid option available.
